# Families of random variables varying kth moment

Tags: probability-theory

Given a random variable, we can translate the density function to get any mean we want.  Then we can fix the mean and vary the width of the density function to get any variance we want.  Is there an operation that we can then do to keep the mean and variance fixed, but vary the third moment to get whatever we want?  Can we keep doing this?

Comment: Have you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_problem ?  You cannot get (for instance) $E X^4 < 0$ no matter how you've shifted things around.

Comment: Sure. How about this: is there a way to vary the moment within the allowed values? It looks like the only requirement is that the Hanke matrix be positive semidefinite.

Comment: What do you mean by *the allowed values* here.  If your target sequence of moments is restricted to be a moment sequence, then your answer is *yes*, trivially.  But that's probably not what you have in mind.